# How do you get the markers in the map object / using ui-leaflet

Tags: angularjs, ui-leaflet

I'm trying to write a popUp function but I can't seem to figure out how to bind anything to the markers on my map.

```
<leaflet id="owmMap" event-broadcast="events" center="center" markers="markers" layers="layers"></leaflet>
```

I've been trying this for a while but it comes back empty

```
 $scope.markers
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to bind the content of your $scope.markers variable to the markers attribut uf your  element.

To bind a Variable from the scope to the HTML you need to use interpollation like this:

```
<leaflet markers={{markers}} />
```

Comment: Yes, but I was under the impression they were already part of the scope. Was I wrong to assume this.

Comment: Just tried "markers={{markers}}' and it breaks the code.

Comment: it depends on the element <leaflet> is this a directive you made by yourself? could you post some code of it?

Comment: no this is based on ui-leaflet. My bad I should have posted that. I have been through their docs like15 times and I havn't been able to figure it out yet. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet

Comment: did you define and add a controller like it's documented on the angular-ui page? '<div ng-controller="MarkerController">
    <leaflet markers="markers" center="osloCenter"></leaflet>
</div>' --> http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/#!/examples/marker ?

Comment: Yes, the directive i'm using is in the top of this message.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it appears that I was correct and you can access the markers like so $scope.markers. Why it was not working for me, appears to have been when I was was trying to access them on the page. Sorry and thanks to @virth for tying to help.